# SQL Server : convert multiple rows in single column

Tags: sql-server, csv

I am running into an issue with T-SQL code. There is a CSV file that I need to import and transform into a SQL Server table. The problem is that the CSV file is not correctly format and looks like this:

```
Recipe,Recipe,Recipe,Recipe,...
0,1,3,4,...
Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4,...
...
```

The final result would need to be at least like this:

```
Recipe,0,Data1,...
Recipe,1,Data2,...
Recipe,3,Data3,...
Recipe,4,Data4,...
...
```

I have used FOR XML PATH to get all rows into one single string but I did not end up with anything good.

The information I have :

- I always know the number of rows and columns that the file has.
- I am using SQL Server 2016
- I do not have sysadmin rights

Any help to show me the right path would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You have a csv and you want to turn it into a table with more than 600 columns???

Comment: It could be 1 column and 1 row for each recipe

Comment: If its just a one time thing why don't you edit the csv instead? Transposing will be much easier

Comment: Like Sean, I doubt you really need 600 columns. Personally, though, I think you'd be better off doing to task outside of SQL; if you must. You could easily open the file in Excel and copy and paste transform the data.

Comment: There is a lot of CSV files that will need to pass by that query and those CSV files will be modified sometimes. I would like to be able to reimport them in a SQL table with this.

Comment: Sounds like you need to fix the export process.

Comment: Well...each row contains the values for a column and you said there are more than 600 rows. Something is very off here. You certainly don't want to continue sticking multiple values into a single cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'Recipe,Recipe,Recipe,Recipe
0,1,3,4
Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4'

;with cte as (
    Select CN=A.RetSeq
          ,RN=B.RetSeq
          ,Value=B.RetVal
     From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](@S,char(13)+char(10)) A
     Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](A.RetVal,',') B
)
Select Str = Stuff((Select ',' +Value From cte Where RN=A.RN Order By CN For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
 From (Select Distinct RN from cte) A
 Order By A.RN
```

**Returns**

```
Str
Recipe,0,Data1
Recipe,1,Data2
Recipe,3,Data3
Recipe,4,Data4
```

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
          ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```

**EDIT - OPTION WITHOUT FUNCTION**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'Recipe,Recipe,Recipe,Recipe
0,1,3,4
Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4'

;with cte as (
    Select CN=A.RetSeq
          ,RN=B.RetSeq
          ,Value=B.RetVal
     From  (
            Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
                  ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
            From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@S,char(13)+char(10),'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
            Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
           ) A
     Cross Apply (
                    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
                          ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.RetVal,',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                 )  B
)
Select Str = Stuff((Select ',' +Value From cte Where RN=A.RN Order By CN For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
 From (Select Distinct RN from cte) A
 Order By RN
```

---

**Edit JSON OPTION -- Correcting for Double Quotes**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'Recipe,Recipe,Recipe,Recipe
1,,3,4
Data1,Data2,Data"3,Data4'


;with cte as (
Select CN    = A.[key]
      ,RN    = B.[Key]
      ,Value = replace(B.Value,'||','"')
 From OpenJSON('["'+replace(replace(@S,'"','||'),char(13)+char(10),'","')+'"]')  A
 Cross Apply ( 
               Select *
                From OpenJSON('["'+replace(A.Value,',','","')+'"]')  
             ) B
)
Select Str = Stuff((Select ',' +Value From cte Where RN=A.RN Order By CN For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
 From (Select Distinct RN from cte) A
 Order By RN
```

**Returns**

```
Str
Recipe,1,Data1
Recipe,,Data2     -- null (2 is missing
Recipe,3,Data"3   -- has double quote
Recipe,4,Data4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Really appreciated! I am having some small issues with it but I think I can work with this! It looks quite long for 73 Recipes / 868 rows (3:30min)

Comment: To complicate stuff a little bit, there are null values sometimes like this: 
Recipe,Recipe,
,1
a,b
c,d
,9

Comment: @FrancisHenry Happy it helped.   3.5 minutes seems long to me, for example, I have a similar process 7,000 equities and 140 elements ... 6.8 seconds on my laptop.

Comment: @FrancisHenry Regarding the nulls.  Let me take a peek

Comment: @FrancisHenry XML really does not like NULLS ... I even tried For XML Path(''),ELEMENTS XSINIL  but that did not help,  I would suggest replacing ,, with ,NULL,   for example  Set @S=replace(@S,',,',',NULL,')

Comment: @FrancisHenry Since you are on 2016, there is a JSON option.  Give me a few to test

Comment: @FrancisHenry See Edit JSON option.  Should be faster as well.  Let me know.

Comment: With your code it takes about 1:15minutes, but my last rowhas &#x0D after each column.

Comment: @FrancisHenry  &#x0D  in the JSON option ??

Comment: I am getting JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '"' is found at position 1.

Comment: @FrancisHenry You have double quotes in your data.  The  replace(@S,'"','\"')   should have trapped that.

Comment: @FrancisHenry See EDIT Correcting for Double Quotes.  I did a little hack replacing double quotes with || and then back again

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the csv formatting, there is no double quotes in that csv file.

Comment: @FrancisHenry Perhaps a non-qualified text string with a comma ...  Without seeking the actual csv, I'm not sure I can answer with confidence.

Comment: I think it has something to do with my string being formatted by FOR XML:
DECLARE @Recipes nvarchar(max) = (SELECT Recipe + ',' FROM #TempCIP FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
Thanks a lot for your help again!